# Can password be stored in plain text as long as its in memory, and not persisted in database, files etc.?

Tags: c#, .net, security

Please see the below code snippets (one has the sensitive data like password in plain text and the other encrypts the plain text). I understand if one persists these in files or database etc., need to take preventive measures like setting ACLs etc. so that attacker cannot get to them easily.

But, what if the password doesn't need to be persisted:

1. Is approach 2 really better than approach 1 as the password is in memory only? or, is it unnecessary? or, is there possibility that some one can read through the memory to get to password - always recommended to be in encrypted either in memory or while persisted?
2. What if the object is serialzed and passed across app domains? (please note that I understand if the password is sent via HTTP (network), it needs to be encrypted, but if its just across app domains can I sent plain passwords?

Regards,

**Plain text password code snippet**

```
  [Serializable]
    class PlainTextPassword
    {
        //Password stored in plain text
        private string _plainTextPassword = null;
        public PlainTextPassword(string password)
        {
            this._plainTextPassword = password;
        }        
        public string Password
        {
            get
            {
                return this._plainTextPassword;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Encrypted password code snippet**

```
 [Serializable]
    class EncryptedPassword
    {
        //Encrypted password
        private string _encryptedPassword = null;
        public EncryptedPassword(string password)
        {
            byte[] encryptedPassword = ProtectedData.Protect(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password), null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
            this._encryptedPassword = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(encryptedPassword);
        }
        public string Password
        {
            get
            {
                return this._encryptedPassword;
            }
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approach 2) isn't any more secure than 1) in terms of memory snapshot. You have no control over when the original password is released by GC (as you have little control over GC) - so if you're shooting for security against memory snapshots take a look at

```
SecureString
```

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx

As for tools that can take memory snapshot, take a look on some profiler (like Dynatrace).

Comment: But with the same theory even if its stored as secure string, one has to convert to plain text - say for ex, need to move it across app domains (needs to convert as plain text, as secure strings wont go across app domains), or use it to connect to web server etc.? that means, one can take snapshot at the very instant and will still have the same problem? isn't it? or, am I missing something?

Comment: @Dreamer Some APIs will take a secure-string, but mostly it's about Attack Surface Reduction - if you're password is only in plaintext for a few seconds that's a big improvement than having your password in plaintext for the life-time of the application.

Comment: @RB, thank you. Does it mean secure string much safer than the encrypted string I stored in code snippet 2 using DPAPI? in other words, I can decrease the surface of attack with approach 2 as well?

Comment: I think I got it 'msdn says: Note that SecureString has no members that inspect, compare, or convert the value of a SecureString. The absence of such members helps protect the value of the instance from accidental or malicious exposure.'. Thank you.